# Programming in C how to output inputted string onto the screen?

Tags: c, string, loops

I am trying to to have my program output the words inputted into my program onto the screen. So far, my program outputs random characters depending on what I type. For example, if I input the word hey, it outputs on the screen %. How do I go about fixing this to output the word hey on the screen? My code is down below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    int word;
    char cont;
    for (;;){
        int countword = 0;
        int countpunct = 0;
        printf("\nEnter the String: ");
        while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n'){
            if (word == ' ' || word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&'){
                countword++;
            }
            if (word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&'){
                countpunct++;
            }
        }

        printf("%c", word);

        printf("\nThe number of words is %d.", countword);

        printf("\nThe number of punctuation marks is %d.", countpunct);

        printf("\nContinue? Y/N?");
        scanf("%c", &cont);
        if (cont != 'y' && cont != 'Y'){
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not printing the value of `word`. Use `printf("%c", word);`. Also, it's unnecessary to make its type as `int`.

Comment: If you haven't used a debugger before now might be the time. Step through the code, line by line, while tracking all variables and their changes, and the problem should hopefully become clear.

Comment: move the `printf` inside the loop if you want to print every character

Comment: is there a way i can make my program to print each word inputted on a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `&` with `printf()`. It will print the address of the variable (and not its value)!

Do this instead:

```
printf("%c", word); // notice there is no &
```

Apart from that, I noticed a few things in your code worth mentioning:

`word` is declared as an `int`, but is read and printed as a `char`. Why?

Comment: Remember that `getchar` returns an `int`. And that `(char) EOF != (int) EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop makes it sure that `word` holds either `EOF` or `\n` while it exits the `while` loop.

```
while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n')
```